# How I can choose next branch via bash script

Tags: git, bash

I've written a script to list all local branches in my repository.

```
#!/bin/bash
clear

branches=()
menuposition=0
eval "$(git for-each-ref --shell --format='branches+=(%(refname))' refs/heads/)"
for branch in "${branches[@]}"; do
    menuposition=$((menuposition+1))
    echo "$menuposition) $branch"
done
```

The output is ...

```
1) master
2) foo
3) bar
```

I can use read command to get user input. But, ... How can I, then, checkout the branch choosed by user?

Comment: read about the `select` command for this sort of situation. Good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
options=('Exit')

#for bash version 4 or higher use mapfile.
#Fallback to while loop if mapfile not found
mapfile -t options < <(git for-each-ref \
--format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads/) &>/dev/null \
|| while read line; do options+=( "$line" ); done \
< <(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads/)

select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    if [[ "$opt" ]] && [[ "$opt" == 'Exit' ]]; then
        echo "Bye Bye"
        break
    elif [[ "$opt" ]]; then
        git checkout "$opt"
        break
    else
        echo "Wrong Input. Please enter the correct input."
    fi
done
```

Comment: For the win: 1) `mapfile`, if available is your friend: instead of your `while` loop do: `mapfile -t options < <(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads/)`. Otherwise, you must use quotes: `options+=( "$line" )`. 2) `[[ !-z "$opt" ]]` is an overly complicated way to just say `[[ $opt ]]`. 3) use more quotes: `git checkout "$opt"`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf The reason I added the fallback was `mapfile` won't work for bash versions below 4.

Comment: Oh, I see! Then you could write a word about it in your post and write, separately, the fallback…

Comment: I'd remove the Exit, op didn't ask for it and if you want to exit you just press ctrl+c. Also clear at the beginning is unusual. I don't know any bash command that clears your screen before doing stuff. you can use COLUMNS=20 to limit the line length, so you have one branch per line.